# Quill Editor inserts erroneous tab character when loading saved data with inline indent style

Tags: quill

I'm wondering if the behavior I'm seeing is a bug and figured I'd ask here before submitting to github.

I need to be able to create, save, and edit saved email templates in the Quill editor.  I also need to be able to use the output from Quill in an email, formatted how it was entered in the WYSIWYG editor, so I'm saving the HTML output with inline styles.

I have an issue with the indentation not rendering as it was entered when I load in a saved email template.  I'm implementing the IndentAttributor like the following comment:
https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1274#issuecomment-303619625

I dug into what Quill is doing and found in matchStyles() a tab character is getting inserted if textIndent is found.

Offending code in quill.js:

```
 function matchStyles(node, delta) {
  var formats = {};
  var style = node.style || {};
  if (style.fontStyle && computeStyle(node).fontStyle === 'italic') {
    formats.italic = true;
  }
  if (style.fontWeight && (computeStyle(node).fontWeight.startsWith('bold') || parseInt(computeStyle(node).fontWeight) >= 700)) {
    formats.bold = true;
  }
  if (Object.keys(formats).length > 0) {
    delta = applyFormat(delta, formats);
  }
  if (parseFloat(style.textIndent || 0) > 0) {
    // Could be 0.5in
    delta = new _quillDelta2.default().insert('\t').concat(delta);
  }
  return delta;
}
```

I tested a change to the quill.js node_module to check for text-indent style.  However, I'm not trying to hack the editor for a specific need and I'm not familiar enough with the editor to know whether or not this will have a negative impact on anything else.

```
function matchStyles(node, delta) {
  console.log('in matchStyles()');
  var formats = {};
  var style = node.style || {};
  if (style.fontStyle && computeStyle(node).fontStyle === 'italic') {
    formats.italic = true;
  }
  if (style.fontWeight && (computeStyle(node).fontWeight.startsWith('bold') || parseInt(computeStyle(node).fontWeight) >= 700)) {
    formats.bold = true;
  }
  if (Object.keys(formats).length > 0) {
    delta = applyFormat(delta, formats);
  }
  if ((parseFloat(style.textIndent || 0) > 0) && !style.cssText.includes('text-indent')) { //fix to check for inline style
    // Could be 0.5in
    delta = new _quillDelta2.default().insert('\t').concat(delta);  //problem here...
  }
  return delta;
}
```

Example project showing the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-acpnmm

Highlight or inspect the initial text (coming from app.reducer.ts initial state) and you will see the tab character that was inserted.

Should Quill be recognizing the IndentAttributor and not insert the tab character?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Quill in Angular project. I would suggest you to check this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill. With this package you can choose the type of data (Text, HTML or Delta) that the Quill will process, and you can bind the Quill content to some variable. That way you can just store that value of that variable in the database. When you need to load the content again, fetch that value from the database, and again bind the Quill content to that value.

Comment: I am actually using ngx-quill in my implementation.  You'll see the QuillEditorComponent in the app component files.  ngx-quill is basically an Angular component that implements the QuillJS library.  The issue I'm having is on the QuillJS side.  The input on the component eventually boils down to the value in QuillJS where I found the code I linked above.